# Multiple H1 tags in blog, category, tag page?

Tags: seo, wordpress, h1

Now I'm aware that having multiple `H1` tags on a page isn't best for SEO.
Unfortunately, this is how my theme is built. What is the best way to fix?

I'm having this problem mainly in my categories, blog, and tags. It may be in any page that contains multiple posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news: multiple H1's are no longer anything to worry about, and haven't been in a while. More good news: if it still bothers you, you can modify your WordPress theme.

Headings are used to provide structure on a page. Your single blog post page, for example, should probably only have one H1, because what else would you use as a blog post name tag? On the other hand, your Category page may display multiple blog post titles, descriptions, first paragraphs, etc. All of these blog titles might be H1's.

Search engines' reliance on headings has decreased since HTML5 introduced new content structure, with `article` and `section` tags. Having multiple pieces of standalone content on a page is commonplace. Search engines know this. This is why, if your page has an H2 instead of an H1, the lower level heading will be treated by them as an H1. Just make sure the heading copy is relevant to both humans and search engines.

That said, if your website theme was coded in a way that doesn't make sense semantically, you may want to just make changes or create your own hierarchy. In that case, make a child theme, and working in your child theme go into the PHP templates for your various content pieces and make the necessary changes. You may also need to update how your various headings look in the style.css file. If all of that seems too much, you may need to change your theme, but this might result in a number of other website issues.

Comment: Wow, i guess that's a little too complicated for me. I will try to hire someone to help me with this. Hopefully not expensive :(

Comment: @Henry Visotski red more https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/169 ++ https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Usage/Headings/h1only ++ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42079503/how-to-deal-with-multiple-h1-elements-on-subpages

Comment: @nikant25 Definitely lots of resources on the matter - here's my favorite: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/the-truth-about-multiple-h1-tags-in-the-html5-era--webdesign-16824

Comment: Also, Google's stance on it, purely from an SEO perspective: https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/852131231928135680?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.seroundtable.com%2Fgoogle-h1-tags-23699.html

Comment: @joew: In case you missed the main statement in the first paragraph: You don’t have to change your theme, multiple `h1` can be perfectly fine (if used correctly). So there is most likely no need to hire someone.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's no more a problem to have multiple h1 tags on one page! I have searched a lot and found:

The **number #2 in Google** with a heavy keyword like **"Men Fashion"** is using 2 h1 tags on the same page. one at the top, the other at the bottom footer.

**here are the screenshots**
[image: number 2 in Google search]
[image: scrrenshot 1]
[image: scrrenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

Can you maybe overwrite it in your HTML or php? Try to add eg.  your headline  in the HTML. It did work for me where I could not find the "regular" settings to make a headline. Maybe this will work too in your case.